# How to pass $event from a programmatically created function that takes $event arg on from expected mouseclick?

Tags: angular, mouseevent

I have a click handler on an angular HTML template that passes the $event argument to the handler function. I need to call this function on ngOnInit programmatically to essentially bootstrap my component with default data as if the user had clicked the button:

Here is the template reference:

```
<button *ngIf="options?.addRow"
  mat-button
  (click)="addRow($event)">
  <span>Add Row</span>
</button>
```

Here is the addRow method:

```
addRow(event: any) {
    const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);
    currentData.push(this.emptyRowFromColumnDef); // Append new row to END of table
    this.updateTableData(currentData);
    if (this.paginationEnable && this.paginator) {
      timer().subscribe(() => this.paginator.lastPage());
    }
    timer(1).subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
    event.preventDefault(); // EVENT arg is needed here
  }
```

And here is where I need to programmatically call addRow in ngOnInit() but I need to pass the event as if it were a manual click:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   event: ? // how to define the $event to pass to addRow?
   this.addRow(this.event);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to create a fake event just to pass into your method.  You could make the `event` optional:

```js
addRow(event?: MouseEvent) {
    const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);
    currentData.push(this.emptyRowFromColumnDef); // Append new row to END of table
    this.updateTableData(currentData);
    if (this.paginationEnable && this.paginator) {
      timer().subscribe(() => this.paginator.lastPage());
    }
    timer(1).subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
    event?.preventDefault();
}
```

Then just call it without the event (*since you don't really need to 'preventDefault' when there's not actually an event*).

```js
 ngOnInit() {
   this.addRow();
 }
```

Another way to go could be to create two separate methods, once for your template to call, and one that does the `addRow` logic:

```js
addRow() {
    const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);
    currentData.push(this.emptyRowFromColumnDef); // Append new row to END of table
    this.updateTableData(currentData);
    if (this.paginationEnable && this.paginator) {
      timer().subscribe(() => this.paginator.lastPage());
    }
    timer(1).subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
}

onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
   this.addRow();
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Then your `ngOnInit` can simply call `addRow()`.

---

I must ask though, why do you need to `preventDefault` on a button anyway?

If it's inside a form and you don't want it to submit the form, you can set the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) to 'button': `<button type="button">`.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `event` an optional parameter:

```js
import { noop } from 'rxjs';

addRow(event?: any) {
    const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);
    currentData.push(this.emptyRowFromColumnDef); // Append new row to END of table
    this.updateTableData(currentData);
    if (this.paginationEnable && this.paginator) {
      timer().subscribe(() => this.paginator.lastPage());
    }
    timer(1).subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
    event ? event.preventDefault() : noop;
  }

// ....
ngOnInit() {
   this.addRow(); // without event
}
```

```html
<button *ngIf="options?.addRow"
  mat-button
  (click)="addRow($event)"> // with event
  <span>Add Row</span>
</button>
```